# Why does Math.min.apply not work within a class?

Tags: javascript, node.js, apply

The following code works in Node v7.0.0:

```
Math.min.apply(null,[1,2,3]) // returns 1
```

But this doesn't:

```
class foo {
  min(args) {
    Math.min.apply(null,args);
  }
}
bar = new foo();
bar.min([3,4,5]) // returns undefined
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a return statement:

```
class foo {
  min(args) {
    return Math.min.apply(null,args);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The return statement stops the execution of a function and **returns a value from that function**.

The example() method returns an integer:

```
 public int example() {
    return width * height;
}
```

it will returns a value from that function. width * height.

source docs.oracle.com